# Does the wrong interface implementation violate Liskov Substitution Principle?

Tags: java, interface, liskov-substitution-principle

Let's consider the following interface implementation:

```
Comparator<String> stringComparator = (o1, o2) -> 0;
```

Does it violate the Liskov Substitution Principle?

Comment: What does an incorrect implementation have to do with the Liskov Substitution Principle?

Comment: There's nothing incorrect about that implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, no.  Your example `Comparator` is simply saying that all strings are equal.  This satisfies the contract for a `Comparator` (see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)), and more broadly it satisfies the Liskov Substitutability Principle (LSP).

(This `Comparator` is not useful<sup>1</sup>, and may well be a mistake / bug, but LSP is not violated.)

In the more general case,  a `Comparator` implementation that doesn't satisfy the `Comparator` contract technically violates the LSP.  But you could also just say that it is broken.  You fix it *primarily* because it is broken / won't work properly ... not because of some design principle.

More generally still, not all examples of LSP violations are broken code.  One example is `IdentityHashMap` which (deliberately and usefully) violates the contract for `Map` by not using `equals()` when testing if keys are the same.  (It uses `==` instead.  Correctly, given the purpose of the class.)

LSP violations can lead to unexpected behavior, but not all surprises are bugs.

---

<sup>1 - I can't think of a case where it would be sensible to use this comparator.  Not a `TreeMap`.  Not sorting ...</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This comparator implements a completely valid total order.

Just check the axioms:

- For all `a`, `b`: if `a <= b` and `b <= a` then `a = b` is trivial (antecedents do not matter, consequence always true)
- Transitivity is trivial, because `a <= b` for all `a`, `b`
- Totality is trivial: for all `a`, `b` it holds both `a <= b` AND `b <= a`.

So, even if it had anything to do with Liskov's substitution principle, it's still just a perfectly valid implementation of a `Comparator`.